# will KeepSynced on firebase database reference contribute to concurrent user limitation

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using keepsynced in my apps for user to listen to database reference changes. So let's say when user quit the apps, and the apps is running at background, will it appear as a concurrent user? Is that true that if 100 users are using my apps, with some running it at background, I will reach the limitation of 100 concurrent user quota stated on Firebase Pricing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `keepSynced(true)` on a node keeps an empty listener on that node. As long as you have any active listeners and/or periodically write data to the database, the client will keep a connection to the backend open and thus count as one of your (limited) simultaneous connections.

Comment: So, it is better to call goOffline() when the apps goes to background after some delays? I am using FCM push notifications, will goOffline() disable users to receive the nofitications?

Comment: FCM notifications are unaffected by calls to the Firebase Database SDK.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this @Frank!